# Expanding divs in a container div for different resolutions

Tags: css, html, web, resolution

I've got a HTML / CSS question about growing a div to fit the screen when filled with other divs.

Here's my structure which is inside my "main" div:

I've got 3 divs inside of a container div, with the last div inside the container having an overflow:auto; property (as it has scrollable content). The whole container div is floated left.

How can I get the last interior div to expand with the screen resolution? The problem here seems to be that my container div has no real "size" so when I set it to height: 100%; nothing really happens. Of course this means that if I assign it an actual size, then it won't grow to the resolution..

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have a demo you could link to?

Comment: atleast the code of the structure or a drawing

Comment: Does this help? It sounds like a problem I was having. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130260/how-to-achieve-layout-goal

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked up CSS3 media queries? Here's a [tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) and [demo](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/media-queries/).

Comment: It looks like this will require some hardcoding of resolutions, is this the best way to go?

Comment: You're right; I don't think this is the best way to go. Generally setting `width:100%` to the container div and setting fixed width to the first two divs would have made the last one expand as required, but I believe your problem here is that the parent div is floating and hence removed from the regular flow of the document, so I guess that won't work.